# How to label dots in 'jittered' scatterplot

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to label all my dots in a scatterplot with the name of the country that is associated with the variables, but all the the labels are shifted downwards. Isn't this the proper way to do it :

```
plot(jitter(data$variable1,2), jitter(data$variable2,2), main = "Bivariate relationship between variable1 and variable2", xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(0,100), xlab = "Variable 1", ylab = "Variable 2", col = "red", pch = 15)

text(jitter(data$variable1,2), jitter(data$variable2,2), labels = data$Country)
```

[This is what the scatterplot looks like without labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwPNY.png)
And our dataset is like this:

```
Country   Variable1  Variable2 
France        2          2
Turkey        1          3
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you're using, the current output, and your expected output?

Comment: please put a sample data first

Comment: Sorry just edited it !

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your questions?

```
Country=c("France", "Turkey")
Variable1 = c(2, 1)
Variable2 = c(2, 3)
df = data.frame(Country, Variable1, Variable2)
x1=jitter(Variable1, 2);x2=jitter(Variable2, 2)
plot(x1, x2, xlim = c(min(x1)-1, max(x1)+1), ylim=c(min(x2)-1, max(x2)+1))
text(x1,x2, labels=df$Country, cex=.7, pos=3)
```

[image]